# disable CSRF middleware based on environment in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

In my application I want to disable CSRF when running on my laptop `APP_ENV=local` and on development too `APP_ENV=dev`. Can't get my head throguh how to do it in either routes.php or the web middleware. here's my routes.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    })->middleware('guest');

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function()
    {
        Route::resource('battles', 'BattlesController'); //, ['except' => ['index']]);
        Route::resource('disputes', 'DisputesController');
        Route::resource('messages', 'MessagesController');
    });

});
```

I could use some env file loading magic to ensure the app loads either of `.local.ev, .dev.env, .test.env, .production.env` but I still have to find a way to ensure that the web middleware includes CSRF only when not in local or dev

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way will be to disable the CSRF check directly in the middleware. In order to do that you'll need to modify **App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken** class. Add there the following **handle()** method:

```
public function handle($request, \Closure $next)
{
    if (in_array(env('APP_ENV'), ['local', 'dev'])) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return parent::handle($request, $next);
}
```

Comment: looks like a good idea but it gives a parse error on the line `if (in_array(env('APP_ENV'), ['local', 'dev']) { `

Comment: in 5.6 you don't seem to need this any more. I don't know how they fixed, or where as there seems to be no app env hacking, but they did

Comment: Just a heads up for anyone else. You should never call `env()` from within your Laravel app, except inside config files which are cached. Instead call `app()->environment()` to get the environment.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar trouble with **testing environment** which could be resolved by turning off middleware:

```
class ExampleTest extends TestCase {
    use WithoutMiddleware;
    ...
```